# How to reduce the ram consumption by a python thread

Tags: python, multithreading, raspberry-pi2

I am currently developing a python based application in Raspberry pi 2, which has 1GB of ram.

In my python application I am using threading concept for showing progressbar(the thread will execute the main process and the normal loop executes the progress bar in the user interface).

For each and every time the thread is executed, the ram memory is reduced by 8mb and after certain times the program hangs.

sometimes the command on the thread `os.system("raspistill") is not working` otherwise it says `maximum recursion depth exceeded`.

Can anyone help me for clearing the above case?

```
def waiting2(wt):
    wt.minsize(480,320)
    wt.title("Reading")
    wt.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    def animate():
        """ cycle through """
        img = next(pictures)
        label["image"] = img
        wt.after(delay, animate)
    label = Tkinter.Label(wt)
    label.place(x=150,y=60)
    fname_list = \
    ['/home/pi/1/1 (1).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (2).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (3).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (4).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (5).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (6).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (7).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (8).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (9).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (10).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (11).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (12).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (13).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (14).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (15).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (16).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (17).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (18).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (19).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (20).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (21).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (22).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (23).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (24).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (25).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (26).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (27).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (28).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (29).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (30).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (31).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (32).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (33).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (34).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (35).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (36).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (37).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (38).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (39).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (40).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (41).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (42).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (43).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (44).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (45).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (46).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (47).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (48).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (49).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (50).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (51).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (52).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (53).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (54).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (55).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (56).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (57).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (58).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (59).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (60).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (61).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (62).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (63).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (64).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (65).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (66).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (67).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (68).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (69).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (70).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (71).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (72).gif',
     '/home/pi/1/1 (73).gif',]
    pictures = it.cycle(Tkinter.PhotoImage(file=img_name) for img_name in fname_list)
    # milliseconds
    if batch==1:
        delay=10
    else:
        delay = 40*batchcount
    animate()
    logo7=PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/New2/close.gif")
    button1 = Button(wt, width = 30, height = 30, image=logo7,command=wt.destroy)
    button1.place(relx=0, x=445, y=0)
    wt.mainloop()

def batch_two_big(wt):
    def ext():
        wt.destroy()
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
    os.system("raspistill -o /home/pi/python/%s.jpeg -t 1000 -cfx 128:128 -co 100" %batchcount)
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.HIGH)
    wt.after(100,ext)
    winmain()


def batchcallback1():
    wt=Tkinter.Toplevel()
    t1=threading.Thread(target=batch_two_big,args=(wt,))
    t1.start()
    waiting2(wt)
    t1.join()

def winmain():
    def ext():
        board1.destroy()
    def jump():
        board1.after(100,ext)
        batchcallback1()

    board1 = Tkinter.Toplevel()
    board1.title("PATIENT DETAILS")
    board1.minsize(480,320)
    logo8=PhotoImage(file="/home/pi/New2/read.gif")
    board1.attributes('-fullscreen',True)
    Label(board1, text="SAMPLE ID").place(relx=0, x=40, y=60)
    e1=Entry(board1)
    e1.place(relx=0, x=130, y=60)
    b1=Button(board1,text="READ",image=logo8,bd=5,width=100,height=20,compound='left',fg='black',font='Times 12 bold', command=jump)
    b1.image=logo8
    b1.place(relx=0, x=80, y=5)
    board1.mainloop()
winmain()
```

Comment: Show us the code, otherwise we cant help, anyway just reading your description, something is really bad within your code, what are you calling recursively in the thread?

Comment: Dear Mr. Daniel Sanchez, as I said above, the main window has a button, when I press it, the user interface displays the progress bar and in the background it executes the raspistill command through os.system. The raspistill command is used to take pictures through camera. I am using Raspberry pi 2(Single Board Embedded Linux Computer, contains 1GB ram memory) with raspbian wheezhy distribution. When I parallely monitor the free ram space, for each and every button press the ram memory reduced by 8mb. Once the ram reaches below 50mb it shows the above mentioned error.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, you have a circular recursive call:

```
def batch_two_big(wt):
    def ext():
        wt.destroy()
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
    os.system("raspistill -o /home/pi/python/%s.jpeg -t 1000 -cfx 128:128 -co 100" %batchcount)
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.HIGH)
    wt.after(100,ext)
    winmain()


def batchcallback1():
    wt=Tkinter.Toplevel()
    t1=threading.Thread(target=batch_two_big,args=(wt,))
    t1.start()
    waiting2(wt)
    t1.join()

def winmain():
    def ext():
        board1.destroy()
    def jump():
        board1.after(100,ext)
        batchcallback1()
```

So, `winmain` binds a call to `jump` for the button, then in jump you call `batchcallback1` wich calls `batchcallback1` wich call `winmain` again and restart the loop.
Try not calling `winmain` from `batch_two_big`:

```
def batch_two_big(wt):
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.LOW)
    sleep(1)
    os.system("raspistill -o /home/pi/python/%s.jpeg -t 1000 -cfx 128:128 -co 100" %batchcount)
    GPIO.output(40,GPIO.HIGH)
    wt.after(100,ext)
```

Anyway, making a thread in your `batchcallback1` looks useless, since you just wait for it.

Comment: Yes, But for the each call to batchcallback1, it creates the thread object t1 and for each iteration it consumes 8mb from ram. I tried del t1 command, but not works.

Comment: @SriKrishnan by building a new thread it creates its own stack, so the ram consumed will be always be there, i think you may want to just not create them or take a look at corrutines.